# angular heroes tutorial Master/Detail Components. Why hero change in parent?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-components

I'm following the [Master/Detail Components - Angular tutorial heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3). My question is why `hero` changes in parent too, if it send diferent variable that doesn't bind a `hero` as such. I believe that must not happen.

[Angular example **here** (heroes tour stackblitz.com)](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnnvrbgborag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.html). Relevant code:

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

 <app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `hero` is being passed as a reference. And down below in `hero-detail-component` the `ngModel` changes `hero.name` directly.

And because they are being changed directly, there's no need to emit an event for the parent.

**hero:**

```
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

**hero-detail:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
```

```js
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() hero: Hero;
```

Comment: So [hero] is also a reference to <li * ngFor = "let hero of heroes"> ... </ li> hero variable in *ngFor?

Comment: Yes, a reference of the very same  object (that is inside the `heroes` arrray) as well. Notice that if this wasn't the case, the `[class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"` would never work.

Comment: You know Where can I delve into the references? thanks.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. The official docs on angular.io are very comprehensive and didatic enough, IMO.